# Float over an element that is floating with CSS

Tags: css

Check out my example, to demonstrate the problem I'm having:

http://jsfiddle.net/zWkse/

```
#mymenu {
    float: left;
    z-index: 59;
    width: 60px;
    background: #000;
    color: #FFF;
}

#myleftcontent {
    width:100px;
    background-color:#fff;
    padding:7px;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    float:left;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

#myrightcontent {
    float:right;
    width: 100px;
}
```

On my webpage, there's main content to the left and some notes on the right (left and right `div` elements)

They both are either `float: left` or `right`.

Now Im having a dropdown menu, that rolls down when you click on a anchor link at the top menu.
This menu is "mymenu" in the example.

The menu is also a `float: left`, but I wish it to be floating over the existing elements.

So that the `#mymenu` is floating over the `#myleftcontent`

How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the y part you havent posted is what its dropping down from. That element needs to be positionend so that the `#mymenu` can be positioned absolute taking i out of flow and allowing the z-index to have its effect: http://jsfiddle.net/4hGnL/

```
<div id="menu-container">
    <div id="mymenu">
        MY MENU<br />
        MY MENU
    </div>
</div>
<div id="myleftcontent">
    i gentager successen og giver dig nu chancen for at få én times afslappende aroma therapy massage hos Prani Wellness, der fjerner dine spændinger og får dig i en rus af velvære! 
Thailandsk aroma therapy massagei gentager successen og giver dig nu chancen for at få én times afslappende aroma therapy massage hos Prani Wellness, der fjerner dine spændinger og får dig i en rus af velvære! 
Thailandsk aroma therapy massage
</div>
<div id="myrightcontent">
    i gentager successen og giver dig nu chancen for at få én times afslappende aroma therapy massage hos Prani Wellness, der fjerner dine spændinger og får dig i en rus af velvære! 
Thailandsk aroma therapy massagei gentager successen og giver dig nu chancen for at få én times afslappende aroma therapy massage hos Prani Wellness, der fjerner dine spændinger og får dig i en rus af velvære! 
Thailandsk aroma therapy massage
</div>
```

With the css:

```
#menu-container {
    position: relative;
}
#mymenu {
    float: left;
    z-index: 59;
    width: 60px;
    background: #000;
    color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
}
#myleftcontent {
    width:100px;
    background-color:#fff;
    padding:7px;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    float:left;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
#myrightcontent {
    float:right;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: With `position:absolute`, I believe you can remove `float:left` from #mymenu because it doesn't seem to do anything anyways.

Answer (score 1):

What you want the menu to do is not float but actually have a position of absolute. This will move the menu out of the document flow.

```
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
```

Z-index determines the "layer" that the element will sit on. You can technically assume that all static and relative elements are on layer 0 by default.

Please keep in mind that this will require a bit of planning when it comes to your HTML structure. The absolute element will be positioned relative to its container. So if you have it in a div with a position of relative, the top and left 0 points are at the edge of that container. Else, it will keep going up the chain until it is absolute with the window.

I have updated your fiddle with this new style change http://jsfiddle.net/zWkse/4/

Answer (score 0):

Adding `clear: left;` to `#myleftcontent` will shift it below `#mymenu`.

Edit: Answered with the assumption that "over" meant above. Sorry if that's not what you meant!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want the menu to float?  I think you are on the right track with absolute positioning but do it as a *child* of the myleftcontent div and give it appropriate:

left: 0; 
 top : 0;

type parameters (or with some padding).  And (as mentioned) you want a higher z-index for this menu.

Of course, myleftcontent doesnt have to be absolute positioned.

See also:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp